# When trying to generate a signed bundle I get this error

Tags: java, android, binding

"Cannot find symbol class ActivityLoginBinding"

My build.gradle:

```
viewBinding {
        enabled true
    }
```

My Activity:

```
 import com.example.myapp.databinding.ActivityConfigurarServidorBinding;    

 ActivityConfigurarServidorBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityConfigurarServidorBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View rootView = binding.getRoot();
        setContentView(rootView);
```

This error is only when generating the signed bundle, the app compiles and runs normally, without any errors. What is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding classes are generated when you build your project. Did you change " ActivityConfigurarServidor" class name recently?

You can clean you project (Build > clean project) and build / run your app again.